# Broadcast frame with unknown Ethertype

Tags: networking, ethernet

On my Linux system I captured this Ethernet frame:
It consists of 62 bytes:

```
FF FF FF FF FF FF  00 12 3F 8C BB C2  00 54  E0 E0 03 FF FF 00 50 00
```

Any idea what Ethertype "00 54" is?

---

This is what I get with tcpdump:

10:06:07.093666 IPX 00000000.00:12:3f:8c:bb:c2.0455 > 00000000.ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff.0455: ipx-netbios 50
        0x0000:  ffff ffff ffff 0012 3f8c bbc2 0054 e0e0  ........?....T..

```
    0x0010:  03ff ff00 5000 1400 0000 00ff ffff ffff  ....P...........

    0x0020:  ff04 5500 0000 0000 123f 8cbb c204 5500  ..U......?....U.

    0x0030:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................

    0x0040:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................

    0x0050:  0157 4f52 4b47 524f 5550 2020 2020 2020  .WORKGROUP......

    0x0060:  1eff                                     ..
```

Answer (score 2):

That's not an Ethertype.

Ethernet frames can have a few [different header formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_frame#Types) – "Ethernet II" aka "DIX" is the most common one, but it isn't what the IEEE 802 standard had originally specified.

In the standard [802.2 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.2) (aka "LLC"), the MAC addresses are followed by a 2-byte *frame length* field, followed by a 3-byte LLC header which contains two 'SAP' values (usually identical) indicating the IEEE-assigned protocol number.

(It's easy to distinguish the two formats – an Ethernet II "Ethertype" is always above 0x0600, while 802.2 "frame length" is always below 0x0600.)

```
FF FF FF FF FF FF    destination MAC
00 12 3F 8C BB C2    source MAC
00 54                frame length (84 bytes)
E0 E0 03             LLC header
├─E0                   DSAP (E0=NetWare)
├─E0                   SSAP (E0=NetWare)
└─03                   control
FF FF 00 50 00...    data
```

In this case, you are looking at a frame with SSAP=0xE0, DSAP=0xE0, which indicates Novell [NetWare IPX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internetwork_Packet_Exchange). The packet data starts at `FF FF ...`, which also matches the usual NetWare IPX packet format.

### Update

> ```
> 10:06:07.093666 IPX 00000000.00:12:3f:8c:bb:c2.0455 > 00000000.ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff.0455:
> ipx-netbios 50
>      0x0000:  ffff ffff ffff 0012 3f8c bbc2 0054 e0e0 ........?....T..
>      0x0010:  03ff ff00 5000 1400 0000 00ff ffff ffff  ....P...........
>      0x0020:  ff04 5500 0000 0000 123f 8cbb c204 5500  ..U......?....U.
>      0x0030:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
>      0x0040:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
>      0x0050:  0157 4f52 4b47 524f 5550 2020 2020 2020  .WORKGROUP......
>      0x0060:  1eff
> ```

According to your tcpdump output, it is indeed IPX, and the packet is being sent on socket 0x0455, which belongs to Microsoft [NetBIOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBIOS) and not to any NetWare protocol. (IPX socket numbers are kinda like UDP port numbers.)

NetBIOS over IPX works exactly like NetBIOS over TCP/IPv4 – it handles hostname lookup, it handles "Network Neighbourhood" / "My Network Computers" discovery, and most importantly it carries SMBv1 – the old Windows file & printer sharing protocol.

I don't know about this specific packet, but `WORKGROUP` followed by 0x1E usually means "Browser Service Elections" – again, just part of the whole LAN computer discovery thing. (If it were sent over UDP/IP, it would be a completely normal packet that's seen everyday on Windows LANs.)

I would recommend using `tcpdump -uw mypackets.pcap` and opening the captured .pcap file in Wireshark, which can fully decode all of these protocols.

I would also recommend disabling IPX on the device. (And while you're at it, check if the device has AppleTalk enabled – disable that as well.)

Comment: Thanks for opening my eyes. This is what I get with tcpdump